# Reference request: Some theorems in an article of Grothendieck.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hodge-theory

In *"Standard conjectures on algebraic cycles" Grothendieck* says:

"The first is an existence assertion for algebraic cycles (considerably weaker than the Tate conjectures), and is inspired by and formally analogous to

> **Lefschetz's structure theorem on the cohomology of a smooth projective variety over the complex field**

The second is a statement of positivity, generalising

> **Weil's well-known positivity theorem in the theory of abelian varieties. It is formally analogous to the famous Hodge inequalities, and is in fact a consequence of these in characteristic zero.**"

*My question is:*

*Where can I find (in a book or article) those theorems?*

*The names(of the theorems) have changed?*

***Note: My reference request is for books or articles in the current language!***

Comment: Posted simultaneously on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178511/reference-request-some-theorems-in-an-article-of-grothendieck.  Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

For Lefschetz decomposition: See [this article](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~azinger/mat545/LDnotes.pdf) or try Voisin's book. Or try Chap. 7 of Griffth and Harris' "Principles of Algebraic geometry" on Kahler manifolds.

For Weil's positivity theorem: This probably means the theorem that the Rosati involution is positive. This can be found on most books on abelian varieties; choose one depending on whether you need complex varieties, e. g., Lange and Birkenhake, or Mumford, if you need  the algebraic proof. Check the contents or index of the books for Rosati involution.